# java to objective c with malloc

Tags: java, objective-c, char, byte, porting

How to port this code in Objective-C? Anyone please help.

```
return data.length != 0 ? new Byte(data[0]) : null;  // In Java
```

I am doing it this way, but this does not show the proper result

```
return datalen!= 0?malloc(sizeof(char) *data[0]) :NULL; //In Objective C it is write java data is byte 

**In obj C** datalen int datalen = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data);
```

I am unable to return data value. What is the problem?

Comment: BTW: You would never use `new Byte(byte)` like this in Java. You can use autoboxing or `Byte.valueOf(byte)` as every possible Byte value is cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return a NSData object:

```
NSData* dataObj = nil;
if (datalen)
        dataObj = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:1];

return dataObj;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java you are returning a new object wrapper of type `Byte`; in Objective-C there is no object like that. The object that you are returning in Java represents a single byte or `null` if the byte wasn't there (i.e. the length of data array was zero).

The closest thing in Objective-C would be `NSNumber`:

```
-(NSNumber*) theMethod {
    // Prepare the data and compute datalen
    return datalen ? [NSNumber numberWithChar:data[0]] : nil;
}
```

You would need to unwrap the value on the receiving end:

```
if (returnedValue != nil) {
    char ch = returnedValue.charValue;
}
```

Note that the way you compute `datalen` by dividing `sizeof` by the size of the element works only for C array objects. It does not work for pointers and C arrays passed to your method. If the array is passed into your method, its length needs to be passed as well.

Answer (score 1):

In C, use the `sizeof` operator (i.e. not the function), in this case:

```
int datalen = sizeof data;
```

But I would suggest using NSData like phix23 mentioned, it's much more Objective-C like and comes with a lot of goodies.